# Run an Excel Macro from SSIS

Tags: vba, excel, ssis

So Im busy making an SSIS package and I need to run a macro in an excel document, I just don't know VB or how I would code this in a Script Task.

I have an excel document called something like DATA.xlsm with a Macro called "Formatting"

I just need to have a script task that runs this formatting macro in DATA.xlsm and then saves the new updated document.

Any help is appreciated.

Ive looked at other posts on this but none of them are really helpful, or seem more complicated than what I am trying to do.

Comment: Realize that this approach requires that you license the SQL Server box for Office as the code @kyleHale uses the Office assemblies. This decision will also further complicate life in that Office requires far more patching than normal which can have a negative impact on the uptime of your server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the basic skeleton code in C# to run a macro (you must add a reference to [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms262200%28v=office.11%29.aspx) to make this work)

```
 Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
 Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\\ExcelDirectory\\DATA.xlsm"); // absolute path needed
 xlApp.Run("Formatting"); // method overloads allow you to send it parameters, etc.
 xlWorkBook.Close(true); // first parameter is SaveChanges
 xlApp.Quit();
```

Comment: I tried doing this but I get the error "No overload for method 'Open'/'Run'/'Close' takes '1' arguments

Comment: There are some additional arguments for those methods, you can just add Type.Missing for all the additional parameters. I take it you don't know much about scripting ...?

Comment: Yeah, I don't know anything about scripting. Never done a script task, and never used C# before.