# How to run an MS Access module from SSIS?

Tags: ms-access, ssis

I need to run a VBA function in an MS Access database in SSIS.
I put a Execute SQL Task in control flow and link it to the mdb then wrote a simple query
like that : Select CleanseData() . CleanseData is the name of the method in my access module and
it does some DML things and returns. It does not need to return any dataset to the SSIS. I just set the
return type to boolean.
When I run the package it issues the Error:
[Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing the query " SELECT CleanseData()" failed with the following error: "Undefined function 'CleanseData' in expression.". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20054131/run-an-excel-macro-from-ssis  This is not quite identical since it's excel, but it may prove useful.

Comment: Also, I should point out that it would probably be better to rebuild the function in SQL, VB, or C# and call it directly.

Comment: Thanks @eric. I already used the interop dll and it works fine for me. I think the fastest way to do something for access db would be to do that into ms access.