# Run MS Access macro from SSIS package

Tags: ms-access, ssis, macros

I am creating an SSIS package to refresh and archive data on an SQL Server.

Part of the process requires an update to tables stored in an Access database, this is currently done by running a macro within Access. To save me recreating this macro in SSIS, is there a way for me run it from the package?

I have tried adapting the code found in this solution but it is for running an Excel macro so i am a bit lost.

[Run an Excel Macro from SSIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20054131/run-an-excel-macro-from-ssis)

Comment: Can you post your code and indicate the error you got? You're going to have problems with this because you will need MS Access installed on whatever server is running the SSIS package.

Comment: Here's a sample for MS Access, but it's a bad idea. If you want a reliable system I suggest you move data and logic out of MS Access and into SQL Server. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16929/Execute-Access-Macros-in-SSIS-Package

Comment: Is it just doing an update to a table or is there crazy logic that needs to be done?