# Running macro from ssis

Tags: c#, excel, ssis, sql-server-2016

I developed an SSIS package that ran Excel macros (VS2008, SQL Server 2008 and Windows Server 2008 if I remember correctly - servers were decommissioned). The package was migrated to Azure using SQL Server 2016 and VS2015.

We are now running it for the first time in over a year and it's failing. Original code for running the macro from SSIS was taken from here  [Run an Excel Macro from SSIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20054131/run-an-excel-macro-from-ssis).

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

public void Main()
{
    Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
    Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\\ExcelDirectory\\DATA.xlsm"); // absolute path needed
    xlApp.Run("Formatting"); // method overloads allow you to send it parameters, etc.
    xlWorkBook.Close(true); // first parameter is SaveChanges
    xlApp.Quit();
}
```

Error on line 1 of Public void Main:

> Additional information: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

Interop reference was added although manually because the install (exe) from MS would not do the job.  Maybe the .dll's are no good?  Please help and keep in mind I am a novice in this area.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!!  The issue is, as others have stated in other posts, I need Office installed.  Interop on its own will NOT run macros or interact with Office products.